# Label not shown after a second Window.Show

Tags: c#, wpf

I am fixing an already existing application and I am stuck on some weird problems.

In some part of our GUI, we had operations that takes some times. So we created a little window named `Wait` with a simple message `Please wait...` in it. And we simply `Show/Hide` the window when it's needed.

But here is the problem. The second time we show the window, the `Please wait...` `Label` in is not displayed.

The Wait.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Wait"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Wait" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>Please wait...</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The Wait.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Wait : Window
{
    public Wait()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Finally I just try this in a minimal WPF application:

```
// The window is shown perfectly
m_WaitWindow.Show();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
m_WaitWindow.Hide();

Thread.Sleep(2000);

// The label is not shown, the window is empty
m_WaitWindow.Show();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
m_WaitWindow.Hide();
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, I tried a lot of things like `UpdateLayout` after the `Show` but no effect.

More than an answer on how to solve this, I would to understand why this is happenning ?

Comment: This is very basic and explained well in any introductory book about .NET programming.  The UI thread of a GUI program can only do one thing at a time, just like any thread.  It cannot render your label text at the same time it is busy elsewhere.  Using a thread to execute time-consuming work is well supported in .NET.  Review the Task and BackgroundWorker classes.

Comment: Try `label.Content = "Please wait...";`

Comment: @HansPassant I know that the UI thread can only do one thing at the same time. What I don't understand is that the first time, this is working and all the other times I try that it does not work...

Comment: What OS are you seeing this on?

Comment: @Rikalous, I can verify that it happens on at least Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

As Hans Passant posted you should be doing your long running work on a separate thread other than the UI thread.  If you really insist on doing this on the main thread, the way around was usually to call something like `Application.DoEvents()`.  This call does not exist in WPF, because it is kind of a hack and a sign that you are doing too much work on the UI thread.  But if you really ***MUST*** try to pull this off, you can add this line in right after you show the window the second time:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));
```

It is essentially the same as `Application.DoEvents()` with a few minor quirks.  However the better solution is to spin up a `BackgroundWorker` to do your long running process, while the UI remains active.  More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking the UI thread, as Hans Passant has said.  (Not intending to answer like Dr. Seuss...)

This is fixed pretty easily by doing the waiting / heavy lifting in a background thread.  Your end implementation can vary depending on what version of .NET and Visual Studio you are using, but you can accomplish what you are after with this simple example:

```
// The window is shown perfectly.
m_WaitWindow.Show();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(arg =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => m_WaitWindow.Hide()));

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // The window is still shown perfectly, because the UI thread is not being blocked.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => m_WaitWindow.Show()));
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => m_WaitWindow.Hide()));
    }, null);
```

Note: In your original case, you should also see that the popup window is unresponsive to user interaction -- a good sign you've got the UI thread blocked.